# greycomatrix for RGB image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, glcm

I am trying to find contrast in an image using greycomatrix here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops


img=cv2.imread('leaf2.jpg')


g=greycomatrix(img, [1], [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4])
print (g)

contrast = greycoprops(g, 'contrast')
print(contrast)
```

Here is the error: "The image must be a 2-D array"
How to convert the image to a 2-D array, suitable for the function?

Comment: Converting between OpenCV is skimage isn't hard, but you need to be aware of some subtleties.  I recommend using the following: `from skimage import io, color; img = io.imread('leaf2.jpg'); img = color.rgb2gray(img)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` after you load the image to make it a one-channel, grayscale image.

Or you could load it as grayscale directly by doing `img = cv2.imread('leaf2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`.

Comment: I tried doing that but it gives a matrix with all entries 0. Will that give correct contrast?

Comment: @MuskanBansal Which matrix has only 0s and how do you know it ? If your matrix is big, the `print` function will only show you a small subset of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly load in grayscale by doing `img=cv2.imread('leaf2.jpg',0)`